# rewrite wordpress url for specific page to remove trailing slash and add php extention

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I want to remove trailing slash for a specific page in Wordpress and do some another changes.for example I have this page : 
http://www.domain.com/page/
I want to change the url to this :
http://www.domain.com/page.php
you know because I need send some get request and its so ugly with that trailing slash so any one can help?
thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You would then need to use a rule like the following in the .htaccess file in your www-root:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(page)/$
RewriteRule ^(page)$ http://example.com/page.php/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: hi.thx for your answer.I tried that but it didnt remove the trailing slash and it work when I point to www.domain.com/page.php but it wont redirect it when i go to www.domain.com/page/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following Redirect

```
RedirectMatch ^/page/?$ /page.php
```

**/?** in the pattern above means the trailing slash is optional. This will redirect both **/page** or **/page/** to **/page.php**

Comment: You can use the Redirect in your htaccess.